# storing the data cart into cookies takes a large size

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem when entering data into cookies.

the data is an array and its large size like product_id,name and many more.

but I see some e-commerce websites that have the add to cart data feature not stored directly into cookies but only set it up because when I delete the cookies the data is lost but when adding new data the memory cookies didnt increase.

**so my question is where is the data stored? because I checked it even in local storage is empty**

what i have done is like this:
I enter data into cookies with the data array and change it into a `JSON.stringify`. in this case i just put 2 data in there and i got size 2539 which mean its to large.

[image: Data cart in cookies]

**My Controller add to cart**

```
import db from '../../config/conn';

export const addToCart = (req,res) =>{
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    let reqBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    let cart = [];
    if(typeof req.cookies.cart == "undefined"){
        cart.push(reqBody);
    }else{
        cart = JSON.parse(req.cookies.cart);
        cart.push(reqBody);
    }

    cart = JSON.stringify(cart);
    res.cookie('cart', cart, { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, expired: tomorrow})
    return res.status(200).json(cart);
}
```

**Server**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// import passport from 'passport';
import connection from './config/conn';
import { CategoryRoutes,ProductRoutes,CartRoutes} from './modules';
import session  from 'express-session';
import csrf  from 'csurf'
import cors from 'cors'
import cookieParser  from 'cookie-parser'
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'iCtkGVe0-4FKIGgBopL2QUM9K-jIK9miZhQE',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
     }
}));

app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
    res.header('X-Frame-Options','deny');
    res.header('X-Content-Type-Options','nosniff');
    res.removeHeader("X-Powered-By");
    res.cookie('c_token', req.csrfToken());
    next();
})
app.use(cors({ origin:'http://localhost:3000/',credentials:true}))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api/', [CategoryRoutes, ProductRoutes, CartRoutes]);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(`Server running on port ! ${port}`);
    }

});
```

> What should I do?how to create Cart system in the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

> how to create Cart system in the right way ?

As cheesy as it sounds, there is no "the right way" to do a lot of stuff in programming.
Personally I tend to store cart information in localstorage, which for my cases works fine. Storing it in cookies is possible, but has a negative side-effect that this cookie will be sent with every request, even for an image or an api call (given your api runs on the same domain).

> so my question is where is the data stored?

A lot of websites do not store it in localstorage, or locally on the computer anywhere for that matter. They store it on the server and when you open the page they retrieve it. The cookie mostly only stores the authentication token that is used to get the cart items from the api. Imagine having an endpoint like `http://mywebshop.com/api/cart_items` which returns a list of the items.

Pros of this method that storing in localstorage does not have, is that when you move to a different computer (but with the same login) your cart will be still present. Also, in advanced scenario's, I could imagine wanting to remove an items from all carts that have that item when it is removed from the website.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely the way to go. Store the data on the server, and only store login authentication info (e.g. tokens) locally on the client. Use the client's login to get and return the items from the server to them when they need it.

Comment: I also agree with this solution. It both solves the issue of efficiency (i.e. passing large amounts of data around unnecessarily), and also the issue of security.